# How to create an HTML grid where cells grow to an exact width and extra height is hidden?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to style a page that shows a list of uploaded photos.

The requirements are (applied in this order in case of ambiguity):

1. The photos must be in a grid
2. There must be 3 columns
3. A photo that is too wide must shrink to the column width
4. A photo that is too narrow must grow to the column width
5. A photo that is shorter than it is wide is left as it is
6. A photo that is taller than it is wide is truncated (overflow hidden)

I can do all of the above except for the last one.

I tried the trick with `padding-top: 100%` but all that seemed to do was make everything twice as tall.

So how can I hide the overflow on a cell with defined width and aspect ratio?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.box {
  margin: 1rem;
  width: calc((100% - 1rem * 6) / 3);
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box green">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="box red">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="box red">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x300/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="box red">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"A photo that is too tall"* - in relation to what? Where/how are you defining this height?

Comment: Ah good catch. Fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

Woops ok so I tried the `padding-top: 100%` top trick again and this time it worked.

You cannot apply it to the children of the flex container (i.e. the `.box`) directly, you must have another box inside it like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.box {
  margin: 1rem;
  width: calc((100% - 1rem * 6) / 3);
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.aspect-ratio-box {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.aspect-ratio-box-inside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box green">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-box">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inside">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-box">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inside">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-box">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inside">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-box">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inside">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-box">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inside">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-box">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inside">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box red">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-box">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inside">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box red">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-box">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inside">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x300/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box red">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-box">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inside">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It also fixed that weird extra bit that was showing at the bottom.